# How to trigger touch start and touch end events

Tags: javascript, arrays, touch-event

In my app a user can 'start recording' and their input is saved into an array for example.

```
[{"time":1292,"elemId":"bass"},{"time":1940,"elemId":"highhat"}]
```

How do I then use this information to recreate what the user did?

Feel free to ask for more code, I just didn't want to over-saturate my question.

Thanks.

Comment: What's exactly each element of the array?

Comment: They're the times and ID's of the buttons pressed in my app.